# ETL transpose and cross join part of a table in SQL or Excel

Tags: sql, excel, teradata, etl

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I need to import into a database. The data in the spreadsheet is of the following format.

[image: TableA]

I want to transform the 10 Wk columns into two columns: Week and Value. An example of this transformation I'd like is below (this is just the transformation of the first 3 rows in the table above).

[image: TableB]

Does anyone have any tips on making a transformation like this (either in SQL or Excel)? Ultimately I need to come up with a process to take the data from the spreadsheet of the format in the first table, transform it to look like the second table and load it into a Teradata database. I'm open to doing the transform process using SQL code, Excel or even Python code. Any help/suggestions is much appreciated. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What teradata version are you on?  16.00 has the unpivot function here https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035-1098-160K/rnz1472240714147.html    best bet would be to get this into teradata as it sits, then unpivot it into your final destination table.

Comment: You can also unpivot in Excel with power query

Comment: Thank you both @Twelfth and Scott Craner! Unfortunately we are only on Teradata version 15.10.05.08. So I did a quick Google search on Excel's unpivot operation. Turns out it is super easy in Excel. Here's the link to the guide I followed: https://www.excel-university.com/unpivot-excel-data/

Comment: Without that command, it's silly tedious in sql...you need to create an inner join to a subselect once for each unpivotted column (10 total in your case).  Assuming your data set is within the excel row limit, use excel.